# Custom animation background

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-animation, cgimage

I need to create animated background like [this one](http://cl.ly/image/073s0H0J0k0X). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: try SpriteKit and make frame animation with images

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, look through few Heat Map Libraries in order to retrieve algorithm for such complex gradient.

Here are couple of them: [#1](https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap) [#2](https://github.com/ryanolsonk/HeatMapDemo)

Next step is drawing animation frame by frame.